# Use jQuery to Select the First TD in Each Row of an HTML Table in IE8

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, html-table

I'd like to figure out a jQuery selector that will give me the first td of each row in an HTML table. The first column, essentially. The solution must work in IE8, as I am unfortunately required to support that browser.

Assume the HTML table looks like so:

```
<table id="tableID">
    <tr>
        <td>Cell 11</td><td>Cell 12</td><td>Cell 13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell 21</td><td>Cell 22</td><td>Cell 23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell 31</td><td>Cell 32</td><td>Cell 33</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So, the intended end result is a jQuery object including only the tds which include the text 'Cell 11', 'Cell 21', and 'Cell 31'.

Also assume this variable initialization:

```
var theTable = $('#tableID');
```

The best solution I see based on the jQuery selectors is:

```
var firstCol = theTable.children('td:first-of-type');
```

However, IE8 doesn't support the :first-of-type pseudo-class.

I've tried using :first-child instead, but it appeared to select the text nodes in each tr rather than the td. By that I mean the line break and tabs in the typed HTML.

Obviously, I could solve this with a workaround like a loop, or by adding a class or id to each td I'm looking for, but that's not the point.

Comment: How about you forgett about IE8 ;)

Comment: I would love to forget about IE8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was using .children() instead of .find(). Children just looks at the immediate children, which in this case was the tbody tag that IE8 decided it needed to insert for me. Find recursively searches the entire DOM below the object it's called on.

```
var theTable = $( '#tableID' );
var firstCol = theTable.find( 'td:first-child' );
firstCol.css( 'background-color', 'red' );
```

I double-checked :first-of-type with .find(), and that still definitely throws an error.

It's possible to use .children(), but we have to account for the tbody tag:

```
var firstCol = theTable.children().children().children('td:first-child');
```

Or:

```
var firstCol = theTable.find('tr').children('td:first-child');
```

Comment: Well, the reason it inserts the `<tbody>` tag is because that's proper HTML. If you put that in yourself, you rework your `theTable` selector to grab the body.

Comment: The tbody tag is not required for proper HTML, and I've rarely seen it included. w3.org's [table tag entry](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/table.html#table) says that, beside tfoot and/or thead, a table may contain 'zero or more tbody elements, or one or more tr elements'.

Comment: But if you still put it in there, you wouldn't have this issue at all.

Comment: The fact that you don't HAVE to include the tag would be one of those "bad part" remnants of HTML coding that they would probably love to get rid of. Just like half the stuff in Javascript. Hence the book "Javascript The Good Parts".

Comment: The tbody tag isn't responsible for the issue, nor would putting it in solve the issue. The issue was using .children rather than .find. .find works without tbody, .children doesn't work with it. The sample table I used didn't have a header, so there was no reason for me to differentiate between the header and the body, so there's no need for a thead or tbody. If I had had headers, then IE wouldn't have been aware, and it's assumption would have put my headers in the tbody, which would be incorrect. Either way, IE shouldn't be editing my HTML for me.

Answer (score 0):

The first-child selector does work. You have to query relative to the tr elements.

```
var theTable = $('#tableID');
var firstCol = theTable.find('tr td:first-child');
firstCol.css('background-color', 'red');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rNA6x/

Comment: jsfiddle doesn't work in IE8, so I'm doubting that you tried that in the right browser.

Comment: Also, the td's are only children of tr's, so specifying that the parent that the td is the first child of should be a tr doesn't seem to add anything

Comment: I noticed you used .find() rather than .children(), which led to me finding the correct answer